# Unable to store classes inside my template Linked List

Tags: c++, class, templates, linked-list

I am creating a linked list template class. I am able to store all the basic data types and even structs in it. But it does not allow me to store classes in it. The error it gives is "Error C2512 'Customers': no appropriate default constructor available". And the error points me to the constructor i made of node struct in MyLinkList.h. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
//MAIN FUNCTION
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "MyLinkList.h"
#include "Customers.h"


int main(){

    std::string name = "Abdullah";

    Customers c1(name);

    MyLinkList<Customers> listA;

    listA.insert(c1);

    return 0;
}


//Linked List template header file

#pragma once

#include <iostream>

template <class t>
class MyLinkList {

private:
    struct node {

        t obj;
        node *next;

        node(t obj);

    };

    node *head, *tail;

public:
    MyLinkList();

    void insert(t obj);

    node* searchGet(t obj);

    void Delete(t obj);

    void sort();

    void display();

};

template <class t>
MyLinkList<t>::node::node(t obj) {

    this->obj = obj;
    this->next = NULL;

}


template <class t>
MyLinkList<t>::MyLinkList() {

    head = tail = NULL;

}

template <class t>
void MyLinkList<t>::insert(t obj) {

    node *newNode = new node(obj);


    if (head == NULL) {

        head = tail = newNode;

    }
    else {

        tail->next = newNode;
        tail = newNode;

    }

}

template <class t>
typename MyLinkList<t>::node* MyLinkList<t>::searchGet(t obj) {

    node *curr = head;

    while (curr->obj != obj) {

        curr = curr->next;

    }

    return curr;

}

template <class t>
void MyLinkList<t>::Delete(t obj) {

    if (head != NULL) {

        node *delNode = searchGet(obj);

        if (delNode == NULL) {

            std::cout << "\n\tData was not found in List..n";

        }
        else {

            if (delNode == head) {

                head = head->next;

                delete delNode;

            }
            else if (delNode == tail) {

                node *prevNode = head;  //we will make this prevNode the tail

                while (prevNode->next != delNode) {

                    prevNode = prevNode->next;

                }

                tail = prevNode;
                tail->next = NULL;

                delete delNode;

            }
            else {

                node *prevNode = head;  //we will link this with the delNode->next

                while (prevNode->next != delNode) {

                    prevNode = prevNode->next;

                }

                prevNode->next = delNode->next;

                delete delNode;

            }

        }

    }
    else {

        std::cout << "\n\tThe List is Empty..\n";

    }
}

template <class t>
void MyLinkList<t>::sort() {

    node *nodeA = head;
    node *nodeB;

    while (nodeA != NULL) {

        nodeB = nodeA->next;

        while (nodeB != NULL) {

            if (nodeB->obj < nodeA->obj) {

                t temp = nodeA->obj;
                nodeA->obj = nodeB->obj;
                nodeB->obj = temp;

            }

            nodeB = nodeB->next;

        }

        nodeA = nodeA->next;

    }

}

template <class t>
void MyLinkList<t>::display() {

    node *curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL) {

        std::cout << curr->obj << std::endl;

        curr = curr->next;

    }

}


//Customer Header File
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Customers {

private:

    std::string name;
    int customerID;
    static int id;

public:

    Customers(std::string name);

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Customers& c);

};


//Customer.cpp file
#include "pch.h"
#include "Customers.h"

int Customers::id = 0;

Customers::Customers(std::string name) {

    id++;

    this->name = name;
    this->customerID = id;

}

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const Customers& c) {

    return stream << "Name : " << c.name + "\nID   : " << c.customerID << "\n";

}
```

Comment: a default constructor is one that can be called without parameters, other than that the error message is quite clear

Comment: I know it seems clear but I did make a default constructor(without parameters) for both node and customer class but still it gave me the same error

Comment: Where did you do that?  It is not in the code you posted

Comment: try to compile `auto x = Customers();` you will get the same error message, because thats what your linked list is trying to do as well (actually I didnt fully read the code but that must be the case)

Comment: @NathanOliver No it isnt in the code above but i tried it before still didnt work

Comment: Wait lol lemme try again. If thats the case im a complete idiot

Comment: @NathanOliver You were right thats the issue. Damn silly me. But why does it even require a default constructor as Im not even calling it?

Comment: I was about to answer. You do not need the default constructor, except for a temporary value you immediately discard. If you fix node's constructor, this will compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'll check the other post

Comment: It is calling the default constructor in node::node

Comment: As the dupe says, if you do not initialize a member in the class member initialization list part of the constructor, the compiler calls the default constructor for you.  This is required because all objects must be constructed before the body of the constructor is entered.

Comment: the place where it is called should be hidden somewhere in the full error message (btw thats why you should have included the full error message in the question)

Comment: Pardon me, but do you have a few moments to talk about our lord and savior, the standard library? (now that we've covered the actual error, this is just std::list with less capabilities and extra risk)

Comment: @KennyOstrom So Im trying to create another overloaded constructor for node na. So i tried < node(t obj(std::string a)); >. Doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @KennyOstrom Lol yeah i know. But i just wanted to do it myself yk just for practice

Comment: Do not create another constructor for node. Look at the constructor for node again, and look at NathanOliver's last comment again. What's the value of "this.obj" before you assign something to it? (rhetorical question) Good luck.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanks for that edit Hahaha. I kinda get it now.